# how to append more test cases to a test set using rally rest api and java

Tags: java, rest, api, rally

how to append more test cases to a test set using **rally rest api** and **java**.

I want to add more testcases to that testset. As of now , I can add only collection of testcases to a testset.

What if I have to add few more testcase to a testset?

Answer (score 2):

If you add the Test Cases you would like to appended to the Test Set to an Array, you can then update the Test Set using the `CollectionUpdateRequest` and `updateCollection` method.

```
JsonArray testCaseRefs = new JsonArray();
JsonObject testCaseRef = new JsonObject();
testCaseRef.addProperty("_ref", "/testcase/12345");
testCaseRefs.add(testCaseRef);

CollectionUpdateRequest testsetTestCasesCollectionAddRequest = new CollectionUpdateRequest("/testset/23456/testcases", testCaseRefs, true);
CollectionUpdateResponse testsetTestCasesCollectionAddResponse = restApi.updateCollection(testsetTestCasesCollectionAddRequest);
```

More information is available at, https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide#update-collection

Comment: I tired the above approach i am facing the below error.         
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 405 Could not find web service for ?/testset/208970644908/add.js? using request method ?POST?.  However a service does exist at that path using method(s) ?GET?.

Comment: Sorry i missed /testcases in the URL.The above approach worked for me thank you.